# Firebase: Simply searching for a user

Tags: firebase

Please forgive me if this is a noob question. I am simply trying to search my collection for the existence of a user. I have been closely following the tutorial [here](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html), and I'm unable to produce his results.

```
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/pizza/users");

myFirebaseRef.set({
    "thisguy": {
        name: "Bill Smith",
        location: {
            city: "New York",
            state: "NY"
        },
        skill: "Code"
    },
    "someoneelse": {
        name: "Frankie Bones",
        location: {
            city: "Tampa",
            state: "FL"
        },
        skill: "Jeeps"
    }
});

myFirebaseRef.startAt('thisguy').endAt('thisguy').once('value', function(snap) {
    console.log('we found your guy ', snap.val())
});
```

MY hope is it would give me the result for "thisguy", but it does not.

BTW: I would prefer to use the push method when adding users to a database, but that is not what the tutorial illustrates. Where am I going wrong with all this? Thank you.

Comment: in the example on the page, it appears that the "thisguy" and "someoneelse" are not quoted in the set. try removing the quotes and trying.

Comment: That blog post you are following is quite old (relative to the age of Firebase itself). Firebase added more advanced querying capabilities (through the `orderBy...` methods that Rob mentions in his answer) since then. See https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-11-04-firebase-realtime-queries.html and the current documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: It seems like, since we're looking for one specific key, that a query is unnecessary here. You can just do `myFirebaseRef.child('thisguy').once('value', function(snap) { console.log('thisguy ' + (snap.val() === null? 'does not exist' : 'exists')); });`

Answer (score 2):

Per the [startAt() method docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/startat.html), the behavior of `startAt()` and `endAt()` will depend on which `orderBy*()` method you've defined in your query.

In your query, you have not specified a default ordering, so it is using the Firebase default ordering of first *priority* and second *key*. In that context, the first argument of `startAt()` and `endAt()` is *priority*, and the second is *key*.

To do sorting by *key*, which is what you want in your case, try the following:

```
myFirebaseRef.orderByKey().equalTo('thisguy').once('value', function(snap) {
  console.log('we found your guy ', snap.val())
});
```